# Parse Tree Of Context Free Grammar

Tags: programming-languages, theory, context-free-grammar, parse-tree

I'm trying to figure out how to do parse trees correctly to show whether a grammar is ambiguous or not.

my grammar is S -> xSy | ySx | SS | e

any help would be great. thanks in advance

below is my crack at it...

```
     S
    / \
   /   \
  x     y
 / \   / \
x   x  y  y
```

Comment: Normally, in a parse tree, each interior node is labelled with a non-terminal symbol, and each leaf node is labelled with a terminal symbol. But in your example tree, you have two interior nodes labelled with terminal symbols. It's unclear what you intend by this.

Answer (score 1):

As a hint, pretty much any grammar with a production of the form

> S → SS

will be ambiguous, because if you want to produce three S nonterminals you can do so in two ways:

```
      S                S
     / \              / \
    S   S            S   S
       / \          / \
      S   S        S   S
```

Assuming those S's can actually produce strings of terminals, these two "gadgets" can be put into the parse tree to derive the same string in two different ways.

Hope this helps!