# Prove the grammar are Ambiguous

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, ambiguous, ambiguity, context-free-language

Can anyone please tell me how to prove this grammar are Ambiguous ? thanks in advance.

I cannot find the string which shows the grammar are Ambiguous :(

G2 = { {S}, {a,b}, {S->ab|ba|SS}, S }

Comment: Sounds like homework. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse Tree Of Context Free Grammar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19281360/parse-tree-of-context-free-grammar)

Comment: Another dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43403182/how-to-prove-a-grammar-is-ambiguous-s-sss  Both of these make the essential point about the production `S→SS`